# Картинка в PicturBox, а не в фоне при загрузке

Tags: c#

ээ по принципу в TextButton указываю ссылку на картинку нажимаю ок и она выводиться в pictureButton.
Извените что вопросами заваливаю.
Вот и 2 накатывается

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
            txtDisplay.Text = ("Танк:" + checkBox1.Text);
        if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
            txtDisplay.Text = ("Танк:" + checkBox2.Text);
        if (checkBox3.Checked == true)
            txtDisplay.Text = ("Танк:" + checkBox3.Text);
        if (checkBox4.Checked == true)
            txtDisplay.Text = ("Танк:" + checkBox4.Text);
        if (checkBox5.Checked == true)
            txtDisplay.Text = ("Танк:" + checkBox5.Text);
        if (checkBox6.Checked == true)
            txtDisplay.Text = ("Танк:" + checkBox6.Text);

    }
вот код. когда выбираю что будет выводиться в TextButton4 к примеру.
```

Выводится только 1 значение. Как должен выглядеть код
что бы выглядело в текстовом окне при выборе Танк:текст, текс, текст.
Вот такого вида.
т.е. чтобы  при выборе какой то кнопки текст не заменялся.

Comment: Прошу прощения, а вы не посоветуете видеокурсы для новичка. Т.к. в C# максимум 4 часа сижу. Если вам не трудно, в визуальном - работа с окнами, а не в консольном. Благодарю. P.S. Я ухожу на 2-3 часа.

Comment: к сожалению нет, никогда видеоуроками не интересовался

Comment: Пришёл раньше чем ожидал, скажите а можно как либо с вами связаться?

Comment: я не провожу личных консультаций=)

Comment: ОК, есть вопрос а что нужно прописать чтобы картинка выводилась если есть ссылку на неё?
Что бы она так же выводилось pictureButton1

Comment: по-подробнее если не сложно

Comment: В самом начале изменил)

Comment: `txtDisplay.Text+=" " + checkBox6.Text`

на будущие, если будут вопросы, не редактируйте старый, а задавайте новый, а лучше сначала сами попытайтесь найти решение, умение гуглить в это время и для этой профессии очень важно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (Fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();

    Image newImage = Image.FromFile(fileName);

    g.DrawImage(newImage, 0, 0, 468, 60);
}
```

- [Graphics.DrawImage - метод](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage.aspx)
- [Graphics.DrawImage - метод](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dbsak4dc.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

По видео курсам посмотрите [интуит](http://www.intuit.ru/)

Там есть неплохие курсы. Также очень много курсов по технологиям Microsoft.